# How to upload multiple excel documents into one dataset using python?

Tags: python, csv

I an new to code and I would like to know whether it is possible to upload multiple excel documents into one dataset using python? If so, what is the code for this? All of the code I have seen is used for uploading one single excel document. Moreover, do I have to convert the data into CSV form first or I can use code to convert it into CSV after uploading it?

I am using jupyter notebook in anaconda to run my python code.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure whether "upload" is the correct terminology. Perhaps "import" is more suitable?

Answer (score 1):

By uploading, do you mean reading a file? If so, just create a list or dictionary, open the files and write them 1 by 1 into your list / dictionary. Also, it would be really helpful creating CSV files first. If you want to do it manually you can easily by saving the file as CSV in Excel.